# Docker service create error: no suitable node (insufficient resources on 3 nodes)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, nvidia-docker

Docker swarm has 3 nodes, of which 1 has gpu.
I'm trying to run the gpu service on gpu node.
when I run command:

```
docker service create --generic-resource "gpu=1" --replicas 1 --name nvidia-cuda nvidia/cuda
```

has error: no suitable node (insufficient resources on 3 nodes)

Anyone can help me please?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP7v5.png)

**Solved:**
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/141#issuecomment-356458450

Comment: would that help: https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/2392 ?

Comment: @Lonely it's not help

Comment: @Lonely I updated the solution.

Comment: did we find a solution to this?

Comment: @inquisitive yes, I edited with solution